# How to set a background for whole application in Android?

Tags: android, background

In my application I have a lot of layers and instead of setting a background image to each of them, I want to set a background once and for all. How can I do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Take a look at [Apply a theme to an Activity or application](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyATheme) to apply the background image across the whole application.

Comment: Thank You! So, basically, I define a style with a background image, then in Manifest I put "android:theme" tag with my style and that's all?

Comment: I haven't tried it for the case of a background image, but yes, that's the direction you need to take.

Comment: It works! Though, I have few more problems, like implementing few themes in one activity/application, but I hope I'll handle it.

Comment: You should include relevant code here, in case your link breaks.

Answer (score 11):

Add `android:windowBackground` to your theme:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

And of course make sure your manifest uses the theme for you application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.package.name"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <application
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```