# How To set the BackGround Image for whole application android?

Tags: android

How to set the back ground image for whole application?I have achieved this but in some cases it throwing the Application background as black in some screens.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632731/how-to-set-a-background-for-whole-application-in-android

Answer (score 0):

The thing you see on your screen is not an "application", but a `contentView`. this is made up from several things that can come from an XML file, and from code.

In the end you have several things on your screen that are `Views`. (for instance: linearView with textViews, etc).

Depending on what you have on your screen, you should do somehting to them. It is impossible to say what to do for all cases, as it differs. But in the end you should make sure that the background image is set for the 'big' View, and the views that are on top do not overlay it with something else.

Answer (score 0):

You could set background for entire app activity window using

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable drawable)  
//or  
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(int resid)
```

but of course preferable to set background for root group of activity ContentView